# does synchronization gives Sequential execution in java? if yes, then why do we need threads?

Tags: synchronized

I am a novice to java. Plz help me the with the below query

Using multithreading we can achieve parallel processing and hence very less time to execute any method.

Where as using synchronized, we hold that method/block for only one thread to execute it at a time.Once it is completed, rest of the threads would execute it which sounds sequential execution and couldn't find the execution time difference as well.

So in this case, why cant we program it without threads.

what difference does it make while programming using synchronized with threads or not using threads at all ?

Comment: The point is to only `synchronize` _some_ parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronization allows one to limit sequential execution only to sections of the code where it is absolutely necessary.

That allows one to manage resources that must have serialized access, while allowing the rest of the program to leverage all available CPU cores.